# Why is RichTextBox ignoring \fs in my RTF?

Tags: .net, winforms, richtextbox

I'd like to use a `RichTextBox` to display some text in the start page of my WinForms application, as follows:

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\pard\fs40 Hello World\par }";
```

The `RichTextBox` ignores my font-size directive (`\fs40`). It works in both Word and WordPad.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't here. I am using VS2008 .NET 3.5. What are you using?

Comment: @Petros: well, that's encouraging. It implies that it ought to work, and I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had the following in the dialog box constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
this.Font = SystemFonts.DialogFont;
```

...this causes all controls (and controls on user controls) on the dialog to ignore font settings.

I think I'll ask another question about that instead.